# packages times(-itsc), txfonts, newtxtext/newtxmath, and mathptmx: relation and interactions

Tags: fonts, comparison, newtx, times

I am always using the packages `times` (actually: `times-itsc` from [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/sterratt/progs/italic-small-caps-times-latex) in order to get italic small-caps) and `txfonts`. I use `txfonts` for the `\coloneqq` (:=) symbol. My loading order has traditionally and habitually been `times-itsc` -> `amsmath` -> `textcomp` -> `upgreek` -> `txfonts`. (I'm mentioning the middle three here just in case it matters for the answer; of course I'm loading many more packages around and in between.)

1. I recently heard about the `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` package. Is the idea that I, simplifying somewhat, just replace `txfonts` with it, and that's it?
2. Just now I notice that `newtxtext` is for text and that `txfonts` was already for much more than just some extra symbols (I originally included this in my package repertoire simply for the `\coloneqq` symbol). Should I in my current setup or with `newtxtext` and/or `newtxmath` in place of `txfonts` get rid of any packages? How do `times`(`-itsc`) and `txfonts`/`newtx...` interact or overlap? For example, do `times` and `txfonts` partially override each other? What is the precise effect of me loading first `times-itsc` and then `txfonts`?
3. And how does `mathptmx` compare to the above?
4. Any caveats regarding package loading order, especially with respect to `amsmath`?

*(This question is quite general, so general answers will be fine.)*

**UPDATE:** New insights:

- `mathptmx` supersedes `times`.

  - The superscript numbers are larger than those of `times` and too large for my taste, though this is probably a feature by design.
- `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` supersede (in combination) `txfonts`. With `newtxtext`/`newtxmath`, I get:

  - larger subscript numbers
  - smaller, thicker, and lower-placed footnote numbers
- Italic small caps were previously only offered by `times-itsc`; now `newtxtext` offers them too. (Thanks, Michael Sharpe!)

Answer (score 9):

I just modified newtxtext to add italic small caps. I haven't sent it to CTAN yet but newtx.tds.zip may be downloaded from

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3825336/TeX/index.html

Instructions for manual installation are given in the README.

Michael

Comment: Nice addition indeed

Answer (score 8):

The `txfonts` package uses fonts that have many small (and some big) defects. Thus using `newtx` is surely better. However, these fonts don't have a "Small Caps Italic" variant.

You could use the `times-itsc` font, but beware that they are really a poor version, as they are obtained by scaling the uppercase letters and are badly kerned. Here's how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontaxes}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareFontShape{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{scit}{ <-> ptmscri8t }{}}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Hello \emph{World}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the result is not very good. But not too worse than what you get with `times-itsc`:

[image]

I've never felt the need for italic small caps, to tell you the truth.

Comment: Italicized small caps are useful because I consistently style certain name-like entities (I'll omit the details) in small caps, and textblocks containing those will, in italicized contexts, look smoother when all of their text is uniformly italicized. / I do think that overdoing the styling can be distracting to the reader and it is good for experts to draw attention to this, but there are contexts where this is very useful, as proven (on a more abstract level) by the existence of intricate syntax highlighting schemes for programming languages.

Comment: @LoverofStructure You might try asking the author of `newtx` to add slanted/italic small caps.

Comment: Does my use of `txfonts` override `times(-itsc)`? I mainly need its `\coloneqq` symbol. Any suggestions on what I could omit in my setup?

Comment: @LoverofStructure Yes, your usage will override the text fonts and you'll get txfonts by default, which doesn't really mix well with the (fake) small caps italic, as my example shows (`newtxtext` uses the same fonts as `txfonts`, with adjusted kerning). You can look at [Importing a single symbol from a different font])http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) for the `\coloneqq` problem.

Comment: Oh, as it turns out a *lot* of other macros aren't there or don't work if I omit `txfonts`: `\varnothing`, `\neq` (dependence on `\notsign`), `\lhd` (not sure why), `\Subset`, `\nSubset`, `\nexists`, `\ncong`, `\ntriangleleft` - strange! I guess I'll keep my `times-itsc` (the italic small caps are thankfully not overridden later) and load `newtx...` after that. Thanks!

Comment: @LoverofStructure Note that txfonts pulled a lot of these symbols from AMS symbols, so `\usepackage{amssymb,newtxtext,newtxmath}` should be fine. Even better, the latest version of `newtx` should give you everything out of the box, so update your packages, and use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`. Regarding Michael's answer, you would even get italic small caps with the latest of the latest version of `newtx`.